# excute the dos command "klist purge" in python using subprocess.call()

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I need to execute "klist purge" to remove Kerberos authentication ticket.

I tried subprocess.call('Kremover.bat') and tried Popen as well but didn't work.

Any ideas?

- where Kremover.bat contains the command "klist purge"

Answer (score -1):

Did you try

```
subprocess.call("klist purge", shell=True)
```

or (preferred)

```
subprocess.call(["klist", "purge"])
```

Comment: Didn't work... I have actually tried subprocess.call("klist purge", shell=True)  first before using the bat file

I get 
'klist' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: does `subprocess.call("start Kremover.bat", shell=True)` not work either?

Comment: No that didn't work either.. I ended up using a dummy user to make it forget the ticket. Please let me know if you have any idea why it didn't work I will do the same if i figure it out . Thanks for your help Wayne

Answer (score -1):

because nobody to press "Y"

```
C:\>klist purge

Cached Tickets: (1)

   Server: krbtgt/domain.dom@domain.dom
      KerbTicket Encryption Type: Unknown (18)
      End Time: 4/17/201x 19:46:13
      Renew Time: 4/24/201x 12:46:13

Purge? (y/n) : y
```

Comment: sure but how to pass "Y" to the program then?